# What would cause the error "Couldn't read from the cursor" on Logcat?

Tags: android, cursor

This is the java class that holds the database functions I made for my app.

```
 public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
      public static final int database_version = 2;
      private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " text";
      private static final String COMMA_SEP = ", ";
      private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "create table "
                + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                /*+ TableData.TableInfo.KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "*/
                + TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
                + TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
                + TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASSWORD + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
                + "); ";

 public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
    super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
    Log.d("Database Operations", "Database created");
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
    Log.d("database Operations","Table created");
 }

 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onCreate(db);
 }
 public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name,String password,String email)
 {
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL, email);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME,name);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASSWORD, password);
    //cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_CON,con_password);
    SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    Log.d("database Operations", "One raw inserted");
 }
 public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseOperations dop) //Method used to retrieve data from database
 {

    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL,TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME,TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASSWORD};
    Cursor CR = SQ.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    return CR;
 }
}
```

I noticed that the query statement is what is causing the problem, but I don't know the specific problem with the query statement above in the getInformation method.

```
public void getUserInformation (View view)//This is the function used to call getInformation.
{
    USER_EMAIL = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.signin_emailbox);
    USER_PASS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.signin_passwordbox);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please wait...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    email = USER_EMAIL.getText().toString();
    userpass = USER_PASS.getText().toString();
    if(email != null && userpass != null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Data collected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        DatabaseOperations dop = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
        Cursor CR = dop.getInformation(dop);

    }

    else
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sorry, no email or password was collected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This function calls the other function containing a cursor object. I want to understand what can be the possible reasons why the error is appearing, and what I can do to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Buddy inside oncreate() method you haven't created any table call this below Log statement sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY); Otherwise there is no table to work

Comment: The error is gone now. Thank you

Comment: Always happy to help :)